# How to install virtualenv with pipx?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Using Python 3.8.3, pipx 0.15.4.0

I tried to install virtualenv using:

```
python -m pipx install virtualenv
python -m pipx ensurepath
```

Then I checked to see if it was installed properly:

```
python -m virtualenv --help
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: No module named virtualenv.__main__; 'virtualenv' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

I'd like to use pipx rather than pip to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `venv`.

```
python -m venv new_env
```

Creates a new virtual environment called `new_env`.

Comment: This does not answer the question and has a big typo and doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @j7skov can I point out the **big typo**, please?

Comment: Yeah, you had “vitual” and you just edited it to venv.

Answer (score -1):

just type this instead.

```bash
virtualenv --help
```

`Pipx` installs packages in their own virtual environment and exposes a binary to globally access the package.
By adding `python -m` your are trying to find `virtualenv` in your main `python3.8` install which is not where `pipx` installed it.

`pipx ensurepath` puts the location of those virtual environments and binaries on your PATH so you can use them directly.

`pipx list` will show you the packages installed with `pipx` and the name of the binaries.

You'll see that the binary for `virtualenv` is `virtualenv.exe` hence you just need to type `virtualenv` as the command to use it.